# Hooking up a received serial command string to a bash script

Tags: serial

I am a complete newbie...so out of my depth!

I am trying to get a Pi3 to read an ASCI command string sent by a serial device and connect each string to it's matching a bash script located on the Pi.

I have installed PySerial
I have successfully read the string from the Serial device named " [LOOP01] " 
The bash script i want to match it too works on the Pi when i just go to the containing folder and run it.

My problem is i have no idea how to connect the two!

I will have perhaps 10 command strings i will need. I can make them anything i want.

Any help very gratefully received!
Thanks

**OK,**
thanks to KentRunner i can run the commands, but just not sure how to format and read the data from the serial device?
I need to monitor it constantly. I can create any ASCII string that i like.
Do i need to use readline() and use a **\n** in my command string?

Here is the code so far...

```
import subprocess
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate = 9600, timeout=1)


# map of serial input string to bash script you want to run
serialToScriptMap = {
    "S1": "/var/www/sync/startseamless01",
    "S2": "/var/www/sync/startseamless02"}
    # and so on...

# get the serial input.....
#    I'm just reading it from the user on terminal for test
#    You want to use your PySerial code in here to get the serial input into the 'serialInput' variable
serialInput = raw_input("Serial Input: ")

#   Not sure how to do that correctly! 
#   Also idea is that the data coming in to the Pi is monitored continuously

# now use the serialInput variable to lookup the correct script name from the dictionary
scriptToRun = serialToScriptMap.get(serialInput, "INVALID_SERIAL")

if scriptToRun == "INVALID_SERIAL":
     # we didn't recognise the serial input
     print("The serial input was invalid")
else:
    # valid input, run the script
    subprocess.Popen(scriptToRun)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a `dictionary` that is keyed on the serial input string and has values of the scripts to run.
That allows you to take the serial input and look up the `dictionary` to get the script name to run.

Code would look something like this:

```
import subprocess

# map of serial input string to bash script you want to run
serialToScriptMap = {
    "S1": "/home/pi/script1.sh",
    "S2": "/home/pi/script2.sh"}
    # and so on...

# get the serial input.....
#    I'm just reading it from the user on terminal for test
#    You want to use your PySerial code in here to get the serial input into the 'serialInput' variable
serialInput = raw_input("Serial Input: ")

# now use the serialInput variable to lookup the correct script name from the dictionary
scriptToRun = serialToScriptMap.get(serialInput, "INVALID_SERIAL")

if scriptToRun == "INVALID_SERIAL":
     # we didn't recognise the serial input
     print("The serial input was invalid")
else:
    # valid input, run the script
    subprocess.Popen(scriptToRun)
```

Comment: Thank for your help KennetRunner!

Comment: That has got me on the road! Still a bit lost as i have to continuously monitor the port, and also don't really know how to best read the ASCII data ? Do i use ser.readline() and add a /n to the control string being sent? ie.[LOOP01]\n